# What makes enum -> int a better conversion than enum -> unsigned?

Tags: c++, overloading, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

In the following code, the overload `f(int)` is chosen instead of `f(unsigned)`. Tested with clang 3.0 and gcc 4.8.

```
enum E
{
};

E f(int);
int f(unsigned);

E e = f(E(0));
```

My reading of the standard lead me to think that `enum -> int` and `enum -> unsigned` are identical standard conversion sequences that both contain only an integral-conversion.

> [conv.integral] An rvalue of an enumeration type can be converted to an rvalue of an integer type.

According to [over.best.ics], the rank of a standard conversion sequence containing only an integral conversion is 'Conversion'.

> [over.ics.rank] Two implicit conversion sequences of the same form are indistinguishable conversion sequences unless one of the following rules apply: [...]

None of the rules mentioned seem to apply when comparing the two standard conversion sequences.

What am I missing?

Comment: `enum` has an underlying `int` by default, so I suspect that's why that conversion is better.  If you tell it to use a `short` or `char`, I'd bet you'd get the ambiguity you expect.

Comment: You have to use [`std::underlying_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) to figure out the underlying type of the enum.

Comment: Integral Promotion. It's not actually an Integral Conversion; see [conv.prom]

Comment: `enumerations (7.2) are not integral; however, enumerations can be promoted to int, unsigned int, long, or
unsigned long, as specified in 4.5.` .. but C++03 4.5 makes no mention of enumerations!

Comment: at least it didn't the first time I read it ;)

Comment: Remember enums can be negative as well as positive; `enum {Val1 = -1};`, therefore conversion to int is more natural.

Comment: @Steztric: Close, but not true. Each `enum` is a distinct type, and the conversion rules differ per `enum` depending on the range. Since the original example `enum E` has no negative numbers, it is subject to different rules than your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++11:

[conv.prom]/3

> A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed (7.2) can be converted to a prvalue of the **first of the following types** that can represent all the values of the enumeration (i.e., the values in the range b min to b max as described in 7.2): `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, or `unsigned long long int`.

(emphasis mine)

Then, [over.ics.rank]/4:

> Standard conversion sequences are ordered by their ranks: an Exact Match is a better conversion than a Promotion, which is a better conversion than a Conversion.

So, for overload resolution on the expression `f(E(0))`, the overload `E f(int);` requires only an Integral Promotion (from `E` to `int`, via [conv.prom]), which has a higher rank the Integral Conversion required for `int f(unsigned);` (from `E` to `unsigned` via [conv.integral]).

---

For C++03, the argumentation is the same, though the first quote is slightly different:
[conv.prom]/2

> An rvalue of type `wchar_t` (3.9.1) or an enumeration type (7.2) can be converted to an rvalue of the first of the following types that can represent all the values of its underlying type: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, or `unsigned long`.

[over.ics.rank]/4 is the same.

Comment: @willj From what I know, Integral Promotion is not a widely known feature.

Comment: @willj It's also a bit counter-intuitive, e.g. `char` will convert rather to `int` than to `unsigned char` (or `short`) for overload resolution, for the same reson.